# Playing a user's local audio file on macOS

Tags: swift, macos, audio, avfoundation

I'm developing a music app of sorts for macOS with Swift. I would like to have the user select an audio file using a file picker, store that file/path, then play that file in-app. Right now I am able to get the file path from the picker dialog but I cannot play the file I get from that path (shown hardcoded here for concision) to play:

```
import Foundation
import AVFoundation

var audioPlayer = AVPlayer()

//These create the player from the web; they work as intended
//let audioSourceURL: String = "https://dl.espressif.com/dl/audio/ff-16b-2c-44100hz.mp3"
//let audioString: String = audioSourceURL
//let audioURL = URL(string: audioString)
//var playerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: audioURL!)

let laudioURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: "//Users/.../ThreeThing.mp3")
let isReachable = try? laudioURL.checkResourceIsReachable()


var playerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: laudioURL)
audioPlayer = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)

audioPlayer.volume = 1
audioPlayer.play()
```

This method works when using the commented lines to retrieve a web file rather than a local one.

In a Swift playground, the laudioURL variable shows the mp3 file desired with extension. isReachable shows true. Neither is the case if I give an invalid file path. However, when accessing the playerItem, properties do not show, e.g., audioPlayer.currentItem?.duration.seconds returns nan—and the file doesn't play. I don't want to bundle the files into the app, as they're provided by the user. Is there an effective way to do this or an error in this method?

Answer (score 0):

Have you try using AVAudioPlayer instead?

```swift
let laudioURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: "//Users/.../ThreeThing.mp3")
        
let audioPlayer = try? AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: laudioURL, fileTypeHint: AVFileType.mp3.rawValue)
audioPlayer?.prepareToPlay()
audioPlayer?.play()
```